# Cloud Firestore Query with React - First Character Is Numeric

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a database in Cloud Firestore which I am querying from a React app (created with create-react-app). The original developer has named the fields of a collection that start with a number. Example: 
collection: users
document: Firebase generated ID (1P3clkdlk409C)
field: 2_score

So when I go to query this from react:

```
db.collection('users').get().then(querySnapshot => {
querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
console.log(doc.data().2_score
})})
```

This doesn't work because react 'sees' the number as not part of the function.

Thanks for any help or guidance you can give!

Comment: can you use bracket notation? `['2_score']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the square brackets notation, as follows:

```
console.log(doc.data()['2_score']);
```

Comment: Ugh, so easy... Relatively new user here. Thanks a million for the quick help!